# QGIS 3.6 composer set to extent of map view map?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I can't find the option to set my map composer to the extent of the map view map in QGIS 3.6 as I could in QGIS 2.x version.

Is there some way to set this option in 3.6 version?

[image]

Comment: In 3.4 the buttons are still there. So either you installation is faulty, or they were moved since then. Maybe consult the change log of QGIS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They have been moved to the top of Item Properties:

[image]